# robot framework dropdown test

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I have to test a webpage where i have a dropdown with company names and when i select a value i.e particular company in that dropdown, it shows all the users belonging to that company.
Right now I have written

```
Company Users
    click link  id=CompanyUsers
    select from list by value   id=Customer_id  1234
    wait until page contains   1234
```

But this doesnot seem to be right way of testing.
I need to check against all the values in drop down and i have around 1000 values in it.
Kindly hep me with this. how should i test this?

Comment: Do you have a source code example of the menu?

Comment: What about to use data driven style of RF tests? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style

Comment: @A.Kootstra : I dont have source code of the menu

Comment: I mean the HTML source of the menu.